# How to insert page break among subfigures inside a code chunk with knitr

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

I have the following R arkdown code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  keep_tex: yes
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{subfig}
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
```
## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.width = 20, fig.height=10, fig.cap=LETTERS[1:3], fig.subcap=LETTERS[1:5], fig.ncol=2,  out.width='0.4\\linewidth'}
for (x in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(a = runif(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
  print(p)
  df <- data.frame(a = runif(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
  print(p)
  df <- data.frame(a = runif(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
  print(p)
  df <- data.frame(a = runif(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
  print(p)
  df <- data.frame(a = runif(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
  print(p)
  cat('\n\\pagebreak\n')
}
````

I'd like to have three different figures, each containing five subfigures. I try to break the figure at the fifth subfigure, but it does not work.

Comment: It does not work either

Answer (score 2):

`fig.cap` is designed to take a single argument, and therefore we are going to have to programmatically generate new code chunks for each of the three plots you want. As [explained here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-generate-plots-with-programmatically-generated-captions-using-knit-expand-in-rmarkdown/10989), we can use the `knit_expand` function. I have amended the example provided to include the subfigure captions, and a way to print plots from a list.

I have written the function `splitSubFig` which will limit the number of subfigures per plot. If we go over this number, it will create a new page. Note, you will need to use the `results="asis"` in the chunk header creating the figures:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{subfig}
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)

library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

# Function to create a separate chunk to generate a plot for each item in list
splitSubFig <- function(plots, caption, maxlength) {

  knitr::opts_knit$set(progress = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)

  n <- length(plots)
  numPages <- ceiling(n / maxlength)
  splitPlots <- split(plots, rep(1:ceiling(n/maxlength), each=maxlength)[1:n])

  for (page in 1:numPages) {

    cat(
      knit(text=knit_expand(
        text=(
          "```{r {{caption}}{{page}}, fig.cap='{{caption}}: {{page}}', fig.subcap=LETTERS[1:length(splitPlots[page])],  out.width='8cm', fig.ncol=2, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
for(i in splitPlots[page]){

for(plots in i){
 print(plots)
}

}
```"),
caption = caption,
page = LETTERS[page])))
  }
}

```

```{r, results="asis"}

plots <- list(ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10, fill = "red"),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10, fill = "blue"),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10),
             ggplot(data.frame(a = runif(50)), aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10))

splitSubFig(plots, caption = "Your Caption", maxlength = 6)
```
````

[image]

This function could certainly be improved, but it should be good for what you need!